# How to remove folder path in zip file

Tags: asp.net

I am generating the zip file from this folder "D:\Nagaraj\Dotnet\Zipfile\Zipfile\Filebuild\Hi" within that "Hi" folder has 2 txt files. .....yes Now generating the Hi.zip file.But problem is Within that zip file has this particular path `"D:\Nagaraj\Dotnet\Zipfile\Zipfile\Filebuild\Hi"` and within that hi folder has 2 txt fils. Now I need to remove this path `"D:\Nagaraj\Dotnet\Zipfile\Zipfile\Filebuild\Hi"` and directly generate that Hi.zip file and within that 2 txt file......thanks ....in advance

I am using `sharpziplib` library enter code here

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  StartZip("D:/Nagaraj/Dotnet/Zipfile/Zipfile/Filebuild/Hi",".zip");
}

public void StartZip(string directory, string zipFileName)
{
  ZipFile z = ZipFile.Create(directory + zipFileName);
  z.BeginUpdate();
   string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(directory);
   foreach (string filename in filenames)
   {
     z.Add(filename);
   }
   z.CommitUpdate();
   z.Close();    
}
```

Comment: can you be a bit more precise in your question please? examples would be really appreciated

Comment: download the help file, some where there is the option you search for http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/SharpZipLib_Links.ashx

Answer (score 0):

From the help file, where you add your files, you say how to do you like to show inside the zip.

```
public void StartZip(string directory, string zipFileName)
{
  using(ZipFile z = ZipFile.Create(directory + zipFileName))
  {
    z.BeginUpdate();

    // Create a reference to the directory.
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
    // Create an array representing the files in the current directory.
    FileInfo[] fi = di.GetFiles();

    // here the entryName is the name that you like to show inside zip
    foreach (FileInfo fiTemp in fi)
        z.Add(fiTemp.FullName, fiTemp.Name);

    z.CommitUpdate();
    z.Close();    
  }
}
```